# Javascript output now showing in custom widget

Tags: ajax, jquery, javascript

I have an issue with Javascript that I created for my custom widget.

Here is the code:

```
    var wrapper = $('#wrapper'), container;

    $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.graphcms.com/simple/v1/SampleAPI",
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: {
    Authorization: "bearer ******"
  },
 data: JSON.stringify({
    query: "query  { allProducts { id title } }"
  })
}).done(function(data) {

for( var key in data ) {

     for (var i = 0; i<data[key].allProducts.length; i++)
     {
         console.log(data[key].allProducts[i]);
         container = $('<div id="data" class="container"></div>');
         wrapper.appendTo(container);
         container.appendTo('<input type=checkbox name="id" value=' + data[key].allProducts[i].id + '>' + data[key].allProducts[i].title  );             
     }   

}

});
```

Here is how I'm calling the Jquery in my functions.php file for the template:

```
  function jquery_import() {

          wp_deregister_script('jquery');
          wp_register_script('jquery',https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/3.3.1/jquery.min.js', array(), '3.3.1', true);  
           wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

     }
     add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_import' );
```

Here is how I'm calling my custom javascript file:

```
     function custom_wp_enqueue_scripts() {

        wp_register_script( 'custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), NULL, false );
         wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );

       }    
      add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_wp_enqueue_scripts');
```

Finally, in my widget here is the following div statement:

```
      <div id="wrapper"> </div>
```

Based on my javascript, data is coming in, however, the information is not displayed in my widget. Why it isn't showing in my widget?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Answer (score 0):

Try changing...

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper'), container;
```

To just...

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper');
```

then add var in front of container

```
var container = $('<div id="data" class="container"></div>');
```

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work..